# WYSIWYG clear:both

Tags: plugin-recommendation

How to clear floats in WYSIWYG editor? Not everyone know how to add `<div style="clear:both>"` in HTML mode. Is there any way to add extra button to WYSIWYG or plugin. TineMCE doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple shortcode to add a `<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>`

Detailed Explanation: http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button/

Comment: shortcode is great idea, but couldn't add custom button following that tutorial, maybe WP 3.1 has changed the way buttons are added. Thank for pointing me in this direction!!!

Comment: This doesn't work? I copy/pasted it into a gist. Download and give it a try as plugin: https://gist.github.com/938844#comments

Comment: Setting "overflow: auto" in CSS is a much better way of clearing floats than adding extra markup -- http://blogs.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/

Answer (score 0):

Try the WordPress plugin [TinyMCE Clear Float](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-clear-buttons/). It uses the following HTML markup: `<br style="clear: both;">`. Give it a try.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin.